# GitLab API: upload projects avatar

Tags: gitlab

Is it possible to upload an avatar for a specific project?

I could not find anything about this in the [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/README.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can upload a file then set the avatar url.

See edit-project docs for how to set the avatar URL.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/projects.html#edit-project

```
...
"avatar_url": "http://example.com/uploads/project/avatar/4/uploads/avatar.png"
...
```

Answer (score 1):

It is true that there is a parameter **avatar_url** within the **response** of an edit or list request but it is not included as a valid edit parameter.

The allowed parameters (referred to the docu) are the following:

- id
- name
- path
- default_branch
- description
- issues_enabled
- merge_requests_enabled
- builds_enabled
- wiki_enabled
- snippets_enabled
- container_registry_enabled
- shared_runners_enabled
- public
- visibility_level
- import_url- id
- name
- path
- default_branch
- description
- issues_enabled
- merge_requests_enabled
- builds_enabled
- wiki_enabled
- snippets_enabled
- container_registry_enabled
- shared_runners_enabled
- public
- visibility_level
- import_url
- public_builds
- only_allow_merge_if_build_succeeds successful
- only_allow_merge_if_all_discussions_are_resolved merged
- lfs_enabled
- request_access_enabled
- public_builds
- only_allow_merge_if_build_succeeds successful
- only_allow_merge_if_all_discussions_are_resolved merged
- lfs_enabled
- request_access_enabled

I can not find any possibility to set an **avatar_url**.