# Add project avatar in gitlab using API

Tags: python, gitlab, gitlab-api

During a migration from gitswarm to gitlab we lost all of the projects avatar. I'm trying to restore them via a python script, but while it is clear how to set the path of the avatar via the project settings API, I do not understand how to upload the avatar.
I searched the GitLab API documentation, but I was not able to find anything. Can someone help me please?

PS: [GitLab API: upload projects avatar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40887151/gitlab-api-upload-projects-avatar) is of no help, since nobody explained the upload command

Comment: I don't think there is such a thing, what I do is upload an avatar and then set the `avatar_url`. You can take a look at [this](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/projects.html#edit-project)

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna Ok, but how do you upload an avatar? And how do you set avatar_url, via the avatar property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I was able to upload the avatar of a project via api and python request. There is no need to upload the file first and then set the url, one can simply use the "Edit project" api:

```
import requests

filename = 'avatar.png'
baseUrl = 'https://gitlabrepositoryaddress.com'
url = baseUrl + '/api/v4/projects/' + str(id)
up = {'avatar':(filename, open(filename, 'rb'), 'multipart/form-data')}
authHeader = {'PRIVATE-TOKEN': 'XXXXXXXXXX'}
request = requests.put(url, files=up, headers=authHeader)
```

Reference for the api is here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html#edit-project

I hope this may help someone else