# How do I retrieve and save an avatar from a gitlab project using python?

Tags: python, gitlab, python-gitlab

So I'm creating projects and deleting them by python script using the gitlab python API. That part is working. But a colleague started adding some avatars to some of my autoprojects that I found amusing and wanted to save them and restore them. But I can't figure out how to do that using the api.

The gitlab python api docs for 3.10.0 says there should be a project.avatar attribute I can write to to save it. So I assumed it would also work for reading. But instead there doesn't seem to be the attribute at all when I retrieve the project object.

I'm not wed to using the python api but I can't figure out how to download the avatar using requests either (this isn't something I normally do so I'm fairly green at this part.) I found an answer on *uploading* at [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52400473/add-project-avatar-in-gitlab-using-api) but can't figure out how to reverse it.

This is one of those "easy" things that was supposed to be a silly twist. Do I have to just blow away his work?